# How does CONCAT format date fields?

Tags: postgresql, date, concat, fields

I have the following code :

```
start transaction;

show datestyle;

set datestyle to DMY;
show datestyle;

select 
   concat(timestamp_field, '')
from
   my_table
   ;
   
commit;
```

It outputs this :

```
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 ligne)


 DateStyle (after set datestyle to DMY;)
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 ligne)


select 
   concat(timestamp_field, '')
from
   my_table
   ;
       concat
---------------------
 2004-09-01 00:00:00
(1 lignes)
```

My datestyle change doesn't seem to be accepted. Moreover, concat keeps using ISO to format my `timestamp_field`. I would expect something like this :

```
       concat
---------------------
 01/09/2004 00:00:00
(1 lignes)
```

> *NOTA:* I don't want to use `to_char` function here. I want to understand how concat automagically converts a timestamp/date field.

Answer (score 1):

`ISO` implies `YMD`. If you want `MDY`, use `SQL`:

```
SET datestyle = 'SQL, MDY';

SELECT current_timestamp, current_date;

        current_timestamp        │ current_date 
═════════════════════════════════╪══════════════
 06/24/2021 12:48:32.739225 CEST │ 06/24/2021
(1 row)
```

All this has nothing to do with `concat`, it is the [type output function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html) that is used to format the value as string.

Comment: What is the *type output function*? How to make `concat` outputs `24/06/2021 00:00:00` instead of `2021-06-24 00:00:00`?

Comment: I have added a link for the type output function. There is no way to get the output you want, except if you use `to_char`.